# number of transpositions and the composition

Tags: group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

Let $S_{n}$ symetric groups and $p$ is number of transpostion.

for all $\sigma \in S_{n}$
$$\sigma^{p} = \underbrace{\sigma\circ \sigma \circ\cdots\circ \sigma}_{p\ \text{times}} = Id $$

Is this result always valid ?

Comment: No.  $\sigma^1 = \sigma \neq Id$.  What does $p$ is "number of transposition" mean?

Comment: In $S_3,$ $\\ (123) ^2=(132) $

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: The obvious interpretation of the question is that $p$ is the number of transpositions in $S_n$, so $p=n(n-1)/2$, and a counterexample is the element $(1,2,3)$ of $S_5$ (or indeed the element $(1,2)$ of $S_2$).

Answer (score 1):

Take $(123) \in S_3$ then we can write $(123) = (13)(12)$ i.e it is the product of two transpositions, but $(123)^2 =(132) \neq 1$.